# Why doesn't RadioGroup have three argument constructor?

Tags: android, radio-group, android-radiogroup

Practically all `View`s and `ViewGroup`s support `defStyleAttr` parameter in their constructors but for some reason `RadioGroup` doesn't. I stumbled upon this while trying to set the style for `RadioGroup` programmatically and now I'm left wondering.

Why doesn't RadioGroup have three argument constructor?

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not well-suited for Stack Overflow. The only one who can answer is Developer X, who is unlikely to see and answer your question. Everyone else can only offer opinions.

Comment: The truth lies in the code of Android support library which is open source so anyone can answer this question. I scoured through that particular class in order to figure out why is it like that, because I actually did have a problem with this since I didn't want to use ContextThemeWrapper. I couldn't find a solution so I asked a more specific question which I thought could point me into a better direction. If you still think this isn't a good place for that kind of discussion then please point me somewhere where people are actually willing to help.

Comment: "The truth lies in the code of Android support library which is open source so anyone can answer this question" -- there is no `RadioGroup` in the Android Support Library, though `RadioGroup` is indeed open source. "I asked a more specific question which I thought could point me into a better direction" -- perhaps you might provide a link to that question. "If you still think this isn't a good place for that kind of discussion" -- had you asked a question about how to avoid `ContextThemeWrapper` with `RadioGroup`, that would have been perfectly fine.